# Is there a standard for embedding heartrate data inside of a GPX file trkpt nodes?

Tags: xml, gpx

I am building an app that processes gpx files and I am wondering if there is any standard for embedding heart rate data inside the `<trkpt>` nodes. The [GPX spec](http://www.topografix.com/gpx/1/1/) makes no mention of this but each type supports an `<extensions>` which anything can be placed inside of.

Is there any known usage of using `<extensions>` to embed heart rate data in trkpts? I want to make sure my app will be compatible with devices which do this but I can't see much info about it.

Comment: See the default schema for 'complex' : http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd. Add this schema as the default schema.   Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468549.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found out that garmin has a thing called GPX TPX (Track point extensions) which encodes heart rate and other info in track points. I haven't been able to find an exact list of the extensions or how to use them yet.